# Where is the source code for PyPI, the Python package index?

Tags: python, pypi

I'm having a hard time finding the source code for PyPI. Where is it?

Comment: On bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The PyPI source can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi). More technical documents about PyPI's architecture are:

- [CheeseShop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShop) (general overview with various links)
- [CheeseShopDev](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopDev) (technical documentation)

The name *CheeseShop* is an older name for the Python Package Index (PyPI).

Answer (score 3):

[Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) is the beautiful, modern replacement for PyPI. It will eventually reach feature parity and replace the older system.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is! https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi

It's a Mercurial repository, and you can clone it:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi
```